# Check if a entered value into a 2D list matches any other value in the same column for all the rows

Tags: python, list, input

python help,
I'm trying to get the user to enter a int value, and check it against all other values already in a 2d list. if the new input value is already in the same column but at a different row, i want to ask the user to renter a value until they enter a unique value.

```
num_list = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]]
num_list.extend([[0] * 7])
rows = (len(num_list))-1
num_list[rows][0] = input("Enter Number\n")

# check if their input is already in the list at the same col index
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can transpose a *2d list* from [row][col] to [col][row] with `zip(*num_list)` - that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it,

```
for col in range(1):
    # check the "above" col values; `:-1` means all rows except last
    other_col_values = [row[col] for row in num_list[:-1]]
    while True:
        new_num = int(input("enter: "))
        # if `new_num` is distinct from *all* others, break the while, stop asking
        if all(new_num != ocv for ocv in other_col_values):
            break
    # if we're here, `new_num` can be safely put; so we do that
    num_list[rows][col] = new_num
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).